# Module not found issue in pydroid3

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pydroid

I recently upgrade my pydroid3 to version 3.8.3, after that i successfully installed my self made third party module but trying to importing it gives following error:

**Module Not Found Error**

In previous version, i didn't got such error.In google play store previous version doesn't available.
Please help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It would be better to copy in the post the original error which should include the name of the missing module

Comment: Did u solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Following a similar thread here -[Pydroid 3 'No Module Named PyQt5' Kivy Form](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1062655/pydroid-3-no-module-named-pyqt5-kivy-form-solved)

You can try to either uninstall and do a fresh install of your module to see if it works. If not,revert back your `pydroid3` to the earlier version and see if that works. If you are successful in the latter case then it may be the case that your `modules` aren't supported in the newer version.